# SQLite REAL sum vs total

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, floating-point, sum

Please help me understand the following results given by SQLite3.

```
SELECT * 
FROM quantities 
WHERE product_id=1;
```

> `1|2|1|15,900000
>
>   96|4|1|1,000000
>
>   97|5|1|1,000000
>
>   98|3|1|1,400000`

```
SELECT TOTAL(quantity) 
FROM quantities 
WHERE product_id=1;
```

> `18.0`

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) 
FROM quantities 
WHERE product_id=1;
```

> `18.0`

The last field `quantity` from quantities table is `REAL`.

It seems that the conversion to `INT` is done before doing the `REAL` sum.
Can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have commas `,` in your data in place of decimal point `.`.

When adding up the column values, sqlite just attempts to interpret the column value as a numeric value and gives up until it finds something that cannot be converted to numeric, using whatever numbers encountered so far:

```
sqlite> create table a(a);
sqlite> insert into a values('1,1'),('2.2'),('100foo');
sqlite> select sum(a) from a;
103.2
```

Comment: @user3017078 can convert values to real using `UPDATE Quantities SET Quantity=CAST(REPLACE(Quantity, ',', '.') AS REAL);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem ... it works fine for me in sqlite.
Example below (Are you sure the column is REAL?)

```
create table if not exists quantities (product_id integer,quantity real);

insert into quantities values (1,   15.9);
insert into quantities values (1,   1);
insert into quantities values (1,   1);
insert into quantities values (1,   1.4);

select      product_id,
            SUM(quantity)
FROM        quantities
GROUP BY    product_id;
```

and returns...

```
1   19.3
```

if I use TOTAL( instead of SUM( it also returns 19.3

A working example can be seen at
http://www.datagloop.com/?USERNAME=DATAGLOOP/SO_TRUNC

Comment: sqlite> .schema quantities
CREATE TABLE QUANTITIES(ID             INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY     AUTOINCREMENT,LOCATION_ID    INTEGER                  NOT NULL,PRODUCT_ID     INTEGER                  NOT NULL,QUANTITY       REAL                     NOT NULL);

Comment: @user3017078 Note SQLite doesn't enforce `REAL` - you probably have `TEXT` instead. Check it with `SELECT *, TYPEOF(quantity) FROM Quantities;`

Comment: Ty,

indeed I have:
sqlite> SELECT *, TYPEOF(quantity) FROM Quantities;
1|2|1|15,900000|text

So I have to ensure that when I add a new row the real number text is with dot? Is this enough to ensure consistency?